# unterminated string literal jquery or more than that

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, quotes

Well I know jquery handles single quotes and double quotes differently for strings. What actually I am trying to do is open a popup on click of a link.

Below is what I am appending to the body on click of "a" tag:

```
$(".prop a").click(function() {
                $("body").append("<div class='lang'>
    <span class='propHead'>Security</span><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='cross' >X</a><div class='propText'>This will be having he description of each of the Language on whch you click with a link to pdf  documentatiom</div><span class='propBtmText'><a href='javascript:void(0)';>Download Documentation</a></span>
</div>")
```

But I get unterminated string literal. I see that I have properly appended the div and spans to body, but it just doesn't work.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it is related but your 2nd a href has it's semi colon out side of the quotes.

Comment: _"jquery handles single quotes and double quotes differently for strings"_ - it does? I don't think so.

Comment: What is with the click inside of the click? That is some strange code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HZLHR/)

The code seems to be fine.  If that's verbose what you are using, javascript doesn't like multi-line  strings, so you would need to use this instead:

```
$("body").append("<div class='lang'><span class='propHead'>Security</span><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='cross' >X</a><div class='propText'>This will be having he description of each of the Language on whch you click with a link to pdf  documentatiom</div><span class='propBtmText'><a href='javascript:void(0)';>Download Documentation</a></span></div>")
```

Comment: What I am trying to do here is on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/tS6LU/19/

Comment: @Mike yup.  It was the new lines and a bit of malformed code.  http://jsfiddle.net/8vFEd/1

Comment: I still don't see the nice popup coming up, with that nice CSS applied

Comment: @Mike It's there, try viewing it without the fram: http://jsfiddle.net/8vFEd/5/show/. also, what browser + version are you viewing it with?

Comment: :Gottacha, I need to adjust top and left, btw Now my close doesn't work as it should. On click of one asset, one popup should open and on click of next, its corresponding popup should open closing the first one. right Now when I click X, it closes all and wont open again.
Much appreciated your help on this.

Comment: @Mike rats... I'll have to get back with you on those points. I have to go.  I'll take another look tomorrow, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close your click. At the end add });

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have given proper quote

Comment: and you have not mis any  quote